# How do I call a function when app running in background using react-native-background-task?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, background-task

I want to call `componentDidMount()` or any other function when the app is running in the background using '`react-native-background-task`' component. Here is the code that I thought of using but dont know if this is right:

```js
import BackgroundTask from 'react-native-background-task'

BackgroundTask.define(async () => {
  this.componentDidMount();
  BackgroundTask.finish();
});

export default class MyClass extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.someTask();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain it more specific? If you want to do any think when app start you can do it in App.js's componentDidMount();

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.job();
}

async job(){
     BackgroundTask.define(() => {
       console.log('Hello from a background task')
       BackgroundTask.finish()
     })
}
```

Or:

```
BackgroundTask.define(() => {
  console.log('Hello from a background task')
  BackgroundTask.finish()
})

class MyApp extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    BackgroundTask.schedule()
  }

  render() {
    return <Text>Hello world</Text>
  }
}
```

Comment: I just found out that I can use AppState to call a function when state of the app has changed. Wouldnt that be a better solution?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure which one is better.